# I have two Django sites: how can I make users of site B login with the credentials on site A?

Tags: django, oauth

I have a mother site, call it A. I'm planning a new site, B, and I don't want users to have to create new accounts.

I want all users of A to also be users of B, while the opposite is not necessarily too.

I suppose this require some form of OAuth?

Can you please address me to the best way to do this in Django?

Comment: You login call on B can query against A's database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use OAuth you need to implement OAuth "provider" on site A, generate app key and app secret and make site B use it while authenticating users. This way site B will be just an application that uses site A as OAuth provider (in OAuth terminology)

Answer (score 0):

You could provide a custom auth backend to your new site B. Have a look here: [Custom Auth Backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#specifying-authentication-backends). This way you can try to authenticate your old user with a second auth backend when they could not authenticate against the first one on site B.